# Pandas Sort by ID and Date and find row where conversion happens

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a customer dataframe with the following columns

```
 cust_id| date      | bought
   1000 |2019-01-01 |  0
   1000 |2019-02-01 |  0
   1000 |2019-03-01 |  0
   1000 |2019-04-01 |  1
   1000 |2019-05-01 |  1
   1001 |2019-01-01 |  0
   1001 |2019-02-01 |  1
   1002 |2019-01-01 |  0
   1002 |2019-02-01 |  0
```

I want to sort by `cust_id` and `date` identify how long it takes for them to convert from 0 to 1 in the `bought` column.

So the output dataframe would be

```
 cust_id| time      
   1000 | 4
   1000 | 1
   1000 | 0
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` "cust_id" and get `idxmax`+1 on "bought" (the index of the first "1" +1), if there is at least a "1" in the column, else NaN:

```
(df.groupby('cust_id')['bought']
   .apply(lambda g: g.reset_index(drop=True).idxmax()+1 if g.max()==1 else float ('nan'))
 )
```

Output:

```
cust_id
1000    4.0
1001    2.0
1002    NaN
```